# Cómo puedo obtener un ID que se autoincrementa al momento de enviar un formulario usando AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

Básicamente para poner en contexto, la persona compra una propiedad, paga con Paypal, y luego quiero hacerle un resumen en otra página, mostrando los datos que puso haciendo uso de id_comprador que vendría siendo el ID que se autoincrementa.

Los códigos se encuentran acortadon para no saturarlos de info.

```html
<form class="formulario-pago" id="formulario-pago" method="POST">
    <div class="formulario">
        <h2>Datos personales</h2>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo" id="nombre_completo" name="nombre_completo"></input>
        <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
        <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento">                
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CÓDIGO DE AJAX (SE EJECUTA AL HACER OnApprove EN PAYPAL)

```
 function pagoExitoso(){
  var formulario = new FormData($('#formulario-pago')[0]);
    
  var nombre_completo = $('#nombre_completo').val(),
      fecha_nacimiento = $('#fecha_nacimiento').val(),
     
    formulario.append('nombre', nombre_completo);
    formulario.append('nacimiento', fecha_nacimiento);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: "datos_compra.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formulario,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(){
        success: function(){
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Gracias por elegirnos. Te estamos redirigiendo a tu resumen de compra",
          text: "",
          icon: "success",
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href='resumen_pago.php';
      },5000)
    }
  })       
}
```

#### datos_compra.php

```
<?php 
function obtenerDatos(){
    include("conexionBD.php");
    $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
    $nacimiento = $_POST['nacimiento'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
    $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
    $opcionID=$_POST['opcionID'];
    $identificacion=$_POST['identificacion'];
    $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
    $detalles=$_POST['detalles'];
    $id_propiedad = $_POST['id_propiedad'];
    
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO propiedad_comprada (nombre_completo, fecha_nacimiento, correo, ciudad, departamento, tipo_id, identificacion, direccion, detalles_extra, id_propiedad)
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$nacimiento', '$correo', '$ciudad', '$departamento', '$opcionID', '$identificacion', '$direccion', '$detalles', '$id_propiedad')";
    $enlazamiento = mysqli_query($conexionBD,$consulta);
}
obtenerDatos();

?>
```

#### resumen_pago.php

En la página que quiero mostrar el resumen de compra, tengo esto al principio, pero no funciona.

```
<?php
include("conexionBD.php");
$id_comprador= $_GET['id_comprador'];
echo "<script> alert('$id_comprador')</script>";
$consulta = "SELECT nombre_completo, correo, ciudad, departamento, identificacion, direccion, detalles_extra, imagen, titulo, descripcion, tipo_id FROM `propiedad_comprada` inner join propiedad ON propiedad_comprada.id_propiedad = propiedad.id WHERE id_comprador='$id_comprador'";
$enlazamiento = mysqli_query($conexionBD, $consulta);
$info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($enlazamiento);
?>
```

El error que me lanza de la misma página

```
Warning: Undefined array key "id_comprador" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_bienesRaices\php's\resumen_pago.php on line 22
```

Comment: Deberías considerar una integración a nivel de servidor. Para el caso de PHP puedes hacerlo mediante peticiones cURL a la [REST API Orders de PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/). Esto facilitará las cosas y dará mayor seguridad a tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En php estás obteniendo el ID del comprador de los parámetros de la URL.

```
$id_comprador= $_GET['id_comprador'];
```

Es decir, se espera que la url tenga el siguiente formato:

*resumen_pago.php?id_comprador={id}*

Lo cuál no estás cumpliendo al redirigir al usuario con JavaScript:

```
window.location.href='resumen_pago.php';
```

Deberías incluir el parámetro en la URL antes de redirigirlo. Para solucionarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
window.location.href = 'resumen_pago.php?id_comprador=' + idComprador
```

Aunque para ello deberías tener el ID del comprador en una variable en tu código JS.

También puedes redirigir al usuario usando php después de registrar la compra:

```
header('Location: resumen_pago.php?id_comprador=$id_comprador');
```

Igualmente debes tener el ID del comprador en una variable.

Aún así, no te recomiendo este método, pues cualquiera podría poner un ID de comprador ajeno y acceder a información de la compra. Al igual que cualquiera podría registrar una compra sin haber pagado simplemente enviando los datos correctos a `datos_compra.php`. Podrías usar sesiones. También ten en cuenta que tu código está lleno de problemas de seguridad. Cuidado con el SQL injection.

Como consejo extra, no es necesario hacer esperar al usuario 5 segundos para redirigirlo a la página de resumen. Es una muy mala práctica.

[Función header() de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

[Prevenir SQL Injection en PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

[Sesiones en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias bro. Lo de la seguridad pienso mejorarla, de momento estoy añadiendo lo funcional. Lo que si no me quedó claro es lo del formato de URL, por lo general se aplica en una etiqueta <a> y un href, pero no lo estoy usando, por lo que no sé cómo lo aplicaría en Javascript. Me podrías explicar más acerca de eso bro? Muchas gracias

Comment: @AlexWhitney ya he modificado la respuesta